# Download file from Google Drive with the public shared URL of the file using AngularJs or NodeJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, url, web

I need to download a file from Google Drive using a publicly shared link of the file in AngularJs (client) or NodeJs (server).

Format of the link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qzv5kDJ_0ZNpJybdBNlcDUAItCXh17EB/

Comment: AngularJs: `windows.location = 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qzv5kDJ_0ZNpJybdBNlcDUAItCXh17EB/'`

Comment: `windows.location.href = *` !